# Compression made in JavaScript (like jSend.org) to submitted data for .NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, compression

I'm using http://jsend.org/.

> For compressed data delivery from server to browser there are GZip/Deflate.
>
> In the other direction there is - now - jSEND

But it seems its only supports in the server side: **PHP**.

So the JavaScript library will shrink the data which will be send to the server. The server class will "open" the shrinked data - but this library is only available in PHP.

Is there any solution for .NET?

Comment: looks like an interesting project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I know i am late, but maybe someonelse will find my answer useful.
There already is a .NET implementation for this created by Iván Stepaniuk.

This is the link for his article:
http://blog.istepaniuk.com/client-side-compression-with-javascript/

and this is its project on github
https://github.com/istepaniuk/jSend-Net

Hope this may be of help to someone!!!